# How to log into parse?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

So right now, I have my sign up set up so I can store my sign up data in parse, and move to the next page. But for logging in I am using

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text)
```

The problem with this, it is not checking the Parse database to see if the username and password exist, and if they do then let you move onto the next screen. All this current code is doing is taking whatever you have typed in the username and password text fields and logging you anyways.

So, how do I check the database for the username and password, then if the user exists, log him/her in

Comment: Are you asking how they will be logged in once they sign up? Are you looking to use their login and/or signup screens or do you want to customize it? Do you have examples of your code so far?

Comment: Or are you saying that the login method is actually registering new users? It isn't really clear what your problem is currently.

Comment: Typically sign up creates a new user, but also checks if there already is a user with that 'username'. If the 'username' is already created, the signup fails. Login on the other hand, just takes in the credentials you pass in and checks the database to see if they match. It shouldn't be logging you in if there is no username in the database that matches the parameters. If your code is setup to just make that call, and show the view afterward, you will always be logged in no matter what credentials you pass in. You need to make a check on the return value of logInWithUsernameInBackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a check before actually logging the user in.

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
  (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if user != nil {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  } else {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
}
```

I'm only seeing you running a line of code without any checks. With this, you tell Parse to see if there are any users associated with the credentials you passed in. Then once Parse has some response to pass you (PFUser or NSError), they send that back from the servers to your app and you handle it accordingly.

If there is a user associated with those credentials, then the PFUser object will not be NULL, else, there will be an NSError.

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: I recommend you insert some log statements or breakpoints to see what Parse is actually return back to you. Such as the error or PFUser objects